# Importing projects from "Java Webservices: Up and Running"

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, ant

I'm currently reading *Java Webservices: Up and Running*. The author provides the project files from [this location](https://github.com/mkalin/jwsur2), which is nice. But he doesn't give any details on how to import the projects into Eclipse (or which version is required).

I like that the author presents the material in this way for learning purposes, but I would really like to import these projects into eclipse so I can play around with them much easier than notepad++.

I downloaded Eclipse Luna which has many options for importing projects, but none of them seem to work with the given projects from the link I mentioned. Has anyone used Eclipse with these projects, how did you import them?

Comment: When you say 'none of them seem to work', do you have any specific issues you can mention? By the look of it, they are ant projects, I would import them using Eclipse's "Java Project" after extracting the zip file somewhere local, and select the folder with the file 'build.xml' in it as the parent folder (eg for ch1, I would select jspService as the parent folder rather than ch1). Would that work?

Comment: What I mean by 'none of them seem to work', I mean when I try to enter the URL of the project (that has the build.xml in it), Eclipse won't let me import it. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Download and unzip the projects to a desired location. Then open up Eclipse and go to `File > New > Project > Java Project From Existing Ant Buildfile`.

This will allow you to import the project into Eclipse, view its source code, search, refactor and what not.

I haven't hooked it up to the run configurations as a couple of settings seem pretty messed-up (paths to specific catalogues, tomcat dirs, the classpath) and I'm not really keen on configuring any of those.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could give 2 upvotes for your last comment. I cannot so instead will give 1 for each comment you provided instead. Your suggestion worked! I have never seen this import option and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I got the project build working fine and wanted to share how to do it quick and dirty for anyone looking to do the same in eclipse. Simply follow Tom's instructions above to import the project. Once the project is imported, open the build.xml and modify the following variables to point to your installation location, 'tomcat.home' and 'src.dir'. Run the build, start your tomcat server, and enjoy.

Comment: @Tom since your comment is the answer, post it as an answer and he the credit!

Comment: @aliteralmind I just wanted to confirm this was what Jason needed. I'll also post this as an answer so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources provided with the book are ant projects so this whole question is basically about importing ant projects into Eclipse.

Download and unzip the projects to a desired location. Then open up Eclipse and go to `File > New > Project > Java Project From Existing Ant Buildfile`.

This will allow you to import the project into Eclipse, view its source code, search, refactor, etc.